# Failed to load Python extension for LZ4 support. LZ4 compression will not be available

Tags: python, ros, lz4

I am new to ROS, I just opened a terminal and typed `roscore` and another terminal and typed `rostopic node` and I got this error that says

> Failed to load Python extension for LZ4 support. LZ4 compression will not be available.

I searched and went to https://pypi.org/project/lz4/#files and installed lz4 using `pip install lz4` and after installation the same error exists, what should I do?

I installed ros on ubuntu 16.04
`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full`

Expected output:
/rosout
/rosout_agg

Actual Output:
Failed to load Python extension for LZ4 support. LZ4 compression will not be available.
/rosout
/rosout_agg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the required `roslz4` package (and `rosbag` itself, too) from the separate ROS PyPI:

```sh
pip install roslz4 --extra-index-url https://rospypi.github.io/simple/
```

Answer (score 2):

On macOS you could use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) to install the `lz4` library, and then use Martin Valgur's solution to install the `roslz4` Python package, but you will need some extra environment variables:

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix lz4)/include" \
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix lz4)/lib" \
pip install roslz4 --extra-index-url https://rospypi.github.io/simple/
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me

```
 pip install lz4 #for python2
 pip3 install lz4 #for python3
```

Comment: the poster explicitly said he did that and did not work