# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, ROS, Failed to load Python extention for LZ4 support. LZ4 compression will not be avilable

Tags: python, ros, lz4, rosbag

I'v been writing a code to extract images from bag file

I don't get any error messages but this

Failed to load Python extension for LZ4 support. LZ4 compression will not be available

I use conda environment and my python version is 3.6.13

ros-roslib 1.14.6
ros-roslz4 1.14.10.1
rospkg   1.3.0

And I also installed lz4 with pip,pip3.

[Failed to load Python extension for LZ4 support. LZ4 compression will not be available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754968/failed-to-load-python-extension-for-lz4-support-lz4-compression-will-not-be-ava)

I used the method from the url above but my problem is still not solved

What should I do?

[vscode Teminal data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyDGU.png)

Comment: Have you tried running outside of conda environment and directly on the host ?

Comment: Yes but I still get the error